# Probability of taking a certain time to travel a distance

Tags: probability

A car travels $x$ kilometres per second. For a distance of $d$ kilometres, it takes the car $\frac{d}{x}$ seconds to travel the entire distance. The distance is given by a random variable ($D$) and is represented by the geometric distribution:
$$P(D = d) = \mu(1 - \mu)^{d - 1}$$
Find the probability that it takes $t$ seconds for the car to travel the entire distance.

I am a weak statistics student but I will attempt to solve the problem.

**My attempt at a solution:** My inclination is to represent $t$ as $\frac{d}{x}$ (because both representations stated that to travel the entire distance, it takes $\frac{d}{x}$ or $t$ seconds. Then, is this not just a simple case of finding the probability that the random variable $D = d$ (the exact formula from the question)?